# Must i use a shopping basket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The scenario is when a customer books (telefone or email) a apartment(s) (no shopping cart) a profile is generated. The customer can login and see al the details as directions, address, practical info ect etc.

The are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :apartments, through: :bookings

end

class Apartment < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :bookings
 has_many :users, through: :bookings
end


class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :appartment

end
```

View user

```
.span6
   %header
     %h3.text
        Booking info
      - @user.bookings.each do |booking|
        %ul
          %li
            Ordernumber:
            %b
              = booking.ref
          %li
            Name accomodation
            %b
              = booking.apartment.try(:name)
          %li    
            Price
            %b
              &#8364;
              = booking.price 
          %li
            %p 
              = link_to "Download Route PDF ", "https://docs.google.com#{booking.apartment.try(:route)}", :class => 'btn btn-primary'
```

It can be that a customer rents 3 different apartments in a period of 2 weeks. It is still one booking with the same ordernumber.

I want to show the total price of the (by example) of the 3 apartments. Is that possibly with this setup...Is this app setup correct ? Must i use a shopping basket (with line_items) that is pre-filled in with the booking data ?

thanks...remco

Comment: Does the booking model has order_number property?

Comment: nope...no order_number